# Recommendation for an iOS & Mac app suite with iCloud support for editing RTF files?

Tags: icloud, software-recommendation, textedit

I'm looking for an app suite of iOS and Mac apps for editing RTF files (originally created with [TextEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit)) and which allow sharing the files through iCloud.

I considered getting the [WriteToGo suite of apps](http://writetogoapp.com). This seems to do pretty much what I want. But I noticed in iTunes that these apps were released in 2013 and haven't been updated since. I'm hesitant to pour money into what seems like old apps with little developer support. So I was wondering whether someone can recommend this(*), or recommend another app suite?

There's a related question on finding an [“editor for both iOS and Mac OS X designed for writers”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41824/can-you-recommend-an-editor-for-both-ios-and-mac-os-x-designed-for-writers/) but, as far as I can tell, the options mentioned there don't use RTF as their native file format (being able to convert from/to RTF and the app suite's native file format is not what I'm looking for).

(*) If anyone is using the WriteToGo suite, I was also wondering what the difference is between the two different Mac apps “WriteToGo knapsack” and “WriteToGo pro”?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of an app called RTF Write which does exactly what you're looking for -- it also supports iCloud Drive and iCloud HandOff.  It's free for iOS, the OS X version is $2.99.

http://machsoftwaredesign.com/rtfwrite.html

Comment: Thanks, that does look interesting. I’ve been holding off on upgrading to Yosemite, which seems to be the minimum required version for Mach Write on OS X, but I’ll start by giving the iOS version a try.

Comment: I tried [Mach Write](http://machsoftwaredesign.com/machwrite.html). It doesn't seem to support TextEdit-style lists? Is this coming in a future version? Does [RTF Write](http://machsoftwaredesign.com/rtfwrite.html) support this? I'm not sure what the difference between Mach Write and RTF Write is.